# Ensure field in database record is required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I ensure that a field in my table is required?

For example: I have a posts table and a users table. When a post is saved it requires a user_id field.

Where if I did something like this:

```
$post = new Post;
$postText = "Test post one";
$post->text = $postText;
$post->save();
```

I would get an error because there is no user_id field. I would instead need to do something like this:

```
$post = new Post;
$postText = "Test post one";
$post->text = $postText;
$post->user_id = 1;
$post->save();
```

Is this done by

- overriding the save() method of the Post class?
- hooking into the Model events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, I'm giving you the most basic by using the if statement. Since all the fields are predefined, you can just check if all the fields has a corresponding value. You can use:

```
if($post->text == "" || $post->text == null){
    do something...
}
```

Or yes you can also touch the Model and check it there.

Thanks

Comment: It's better to do `if (!empty())` since an unset variable will throw an error with the code you have.

Comment: Thanks for that. Where would this code go? If you were to put it in the Post model, where would it belong?

Comment: It should be before you call the save() function.

Comment: Thanks @Jed, I'm hoping to put all of this in the Post model but having issues overriding the save() method. Going to open a new question for that.

Comment: you don't need to override the save() method since you're going to check the fields before...